# long text in a css grid doesn't come inline

Tags: html, css

[view when testing the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MQxt.png)The grid i made works with small lines of text but the moment i add a long text, it doesn't stay in line with the rest. How can i make that the text adapts to the size of the grid and not the other way around?

```css
.row:after{
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: inline;
}
[class*='col-']{
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.col-1{width: 8.33%};
.col-2{width: 16.66%};
.col-3{width: 25%};
.col-4{width: 33.3%};
.col-5{width: 41.66%};
.col-6{width: 50%};
.col-7{width: 58.33%};
.col-8{width: 66.66%};
.col-9{width: 75%};
.col-10{width: 83.33%};
.col-11{width: 91.66%};
.col-12{width: 100%};
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
      hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
      hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>some text hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
      hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
      hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
      hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
      hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughugh
      vjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbs
      sfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `it doesn't stay in line with the rest` what do you mean? Can you show us a picture with the expected result?

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/qeoauzah/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If adding long words (like site URL) to grid and that text does not contains any white space, than it will extend beyond your specified grid width. You can use `word-break: break-all` to force-break word when there is no more space for it. Down side of it is that that even short words will break anywhere. But you can apply that only for some specific tags (like links or spans with specific class).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: inline;
}
[class*='col-'] {
  padding: 15px;
  float: left;
  word-break: break-all;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.col-1 {
  width: 8.33%;
}
.col-2 {
  width: 16.66%;
}
.col-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-4 {
  width: 33.3%;
}
.col-5 {
  width: 41.66%;
}
.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-7 {
  width: 58.33%;
}
.col-8 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-10 {
  width: 83.33%;
}
.col-11 {
  width: 91.66%;
}
.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughughvjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbssfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdlhfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughughvjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbssfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdlhfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughughvjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbssfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>hfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughughvjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbssfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdlhfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughughvjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbssfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdlhfjfhufhsdjbdjfhefhjdvhjdghuzghsjhsdghghegheroghroghrogheugverugrughughvjsdbvjsvjsdbvjvbsjvbjsbvjnffgflkvlksvnfsjbjkfghsghsvsdvshvsvjsvsvbsvbsvbssfshvsjvjsvjfvjfjfsvnsvsdhosdhgusohuspghuhsnvnsdvnsdlvnsdlvnsdlvnsdklvnsdl
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ullamcorper quis justo posuere maximus. Curabitur porta dui vitae risus convallis, in tincidunt neque pretium. Sed aliquet massa et dictum sagittis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis
      dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed eleifend lacus nulla, et suscipit massa suscipit vitae. Sed vel felis ac leo convallis ultricies. Donec eget metus malesuada, finibus lectus id, finibus felis. Suspendisse dolor velit, egestas ut
      aliquet et, tempus nec dui. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In pulvinar egestas odio. Sed condimentum, turpis at dignissim sollicitudin, purus enim pretium ante, at sollicitudin augue tortor
      nec magna. Mauris interdum diam a ultrices rutrum. Suspendisse mi quam, auctor ut neque quis, suscipit congue sapien. Donec luctus ac magna at euismod. Fusce ut massa at magna porttitor dignissim. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient
      montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Ut sed felis arcu. Curabitur pellentesque ex nisl, non auctor dui scelerisque vel. Curabitur arcu lorem, facilisis quis felis at, posuere tempor dolor. Nunc magna orci, molestie et lorem eu, tincidunt sollicitudin
      nisl. Fusce non velit ex. Sed lacinia sollicitudin odio id cursus. In cursus nunc id nibh aliquam euismod. Vestibulum sollicitudin lectus in sem gravida venenatis. Sed orci nulla, finibus et finibus vel, scelerisque eget nisi. Curabitur tempor,
      urna non dignissim vehicula, mi nulla ultricies est, eget ullamcorper turpis tellus eu dolor. Proin tincidunt, felis ac euismod condimentum, mauris odio venenatis turpis, nec sodales turpis diam sed nunc. Aenean lacinia metus metus, in sodales nulla
      vestibulum vitae. Donec tempor rhoncus nibh ac dictum. Mauris vitae tincidunt augue. Praesent elementum velit nec dui suscipit iaculis. Etiam hendrerit rutrum leo eu sollicitudin. Quisque in elit eu sapien dignissim lacinia eget non mauris. Duis
      blandit erat sit amet auctor fermentum. Phasellus ac finibus eros. Nam vulputate justo a urna interdum, vitae vehicula augue porttitor. Donec non mi placerat, laoreet erat et, maximus arcu. Sed non lacus dui. Donec vulputate eros sed elit blandit,
      eu iaculis enim faucibus. Vestibulum aliquam dolor id urna volutpat, id venenatis dui feugiat. Integer gravida sed neque ut consectetur. Phasellus non risus quis purus ullamcorper volutpat. Fusce laoreet urna et purus cursus, sed tincidunt risus
      vestibulum. Integer aliquet ligula vel cursus scelerisque. Duis massa ipsum, blandit a urna a, tincidunt laoreet sem. Mauris pellentesque lorem et tincidunt sagittis. Sed rhoncus feugiat sem, at ultrices velit porta non. Donec vitae elit fermentum,
      pulvinar ex nec, commodo justo. Duis eget augue nisl. Quisque viverra nulla eros, at ullamcorper neque cursus ullamcorper. Etiam mauris nunc, bibendum feugiat enim sit amet, tincidunt pellentesque tellus. Nullam malesuada quis nisi sed mollis. Etiam
      auctor arcu ac tellus consequat egestas. Aliquam ac egestas erat, ultrices consequat dui. Ut eget augue id arcu scelerisque molestie. Ut venenatis lacus eget tincidunt pretium. Integer id pretium mauris, ac egestas mi.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Side notes:*

When using grid and applying padding always use `box-sizing: border-box` so that width in `%` will take content width together with padding.

Your CSS has errors. `;` outside of `}` is wrong (like `.col-1{width: 8.33%};` must be `.col-1{width: 8.33%;}`). I think it's breaking your CSS and not applying width to classes.

`max-width: 1200px;` should be applied to `col-*` wrapper, e.g. for `.row`

Comment: i used a lorem ipsum text to test what you say and this didn't work. also word-break had no effect.

Comment: @Falcjh Can you provide JSFiddle link with not working my example?

Comment: It was indeed the ; that broke the css, thanks for pointing that out. Didn't notice it, also the other tips made it look better

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the parent div as: display: block; position: relative (i.e. .row{} not .row::after{})
And then the column div as: display: inline-block; position: relative;

Or use for parent div i.e. .row {display: table} and column div as {display: table-column}